# PHP array sorting not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Below is an output of my array

```
$array1 = Array ( [d] => 5 [e] => 1 [a] => 3 [b] => 3 [c] => 3 [f] => 3 )
```

I want to sort it like...

```
Array ( [d] => 5 [a] => 3 [b] => 3 [c] => 3 [f] => 3 [e] => 1)
```

I am using arsort($array1)

which results in `var_dump($array1)`

```
array (size=6)
'd' => int 5
'f' => int 3
'c' => int 3
'a' => int 3
'b' => int 3
'e' => int 1
```

anyways to fix this?

Comment: add comments for negative rep

Comment: you should probably try `arsort`. Did you try looking up 'reverse asort'?

Comment: don't think there's going to be an in-built function for that

Comment: How come its not working for you @SriNi? When I tried `arsort($array1);`, I got this result : `Array ( [d] => 5 [f] => 3 [c] => 3 [a] => 3 [b] => 3 [e] => 1 ) `

Comment: @prava He wants the values sorted, then the keys as well. Notice how for `3`s it's in alphabetical order (the keys)

Comment: people who are busy in down voting.. at least give reason for down votes...I want to sort values without affecting keys.. as shown in expected result..

Comment: @A.Lau, I got you. Thank you for your clarification. Check my answer Srini and in future, please try to elaborate what result you want.

Comment: @SriNi use sort()

Comment: @Davinder Kumar sort does not hold custom key..It hold values.. but key starts from 0,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array1 = [
    'd' => 5,
    'e' => 1,
    'a' => 3,
    'b' => 3,
    'c' => 3,
    'f' => 3
];

array_multisort(array_values($array1), SORT_DESC, array_keys($array1), SORT_ASC, $array1);

print_r($array1);
```

Here first `array_values($array1), SORT_DESC` will sort the values in descending order and then `array_keys($array1), SORT_ASC` will sort the keys into ascending order and finally both the thing applies to the main array i.e. `$array1`.

```
O/P - Array ( [d] => 5 [a] => 3 [b] => 3 [c] => 3 [f] => 3 [e] => 1 )
```

I hope this time I get what you want. Finger crossed !!!

Comment: this would result in array (size=6)
  'd' => int 5
  'f' => int 3
  'c' => int 3
  'a' => int 3
  'b' => int 3
  'e' => int 1

Comment: Again I confused with what you want. Let me edit it as per you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can work like this its working.

```
    <?php
    $array1 = array( "[d]" => 5,"[e]" => 1,"[a]" => 3,"[b]" => 3,"[c]" => 3,"[f]" => 3 );
    $a = arsort($array1);
    foreach($array1 as $x => $x_value) {
        echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
output:
Key=[d], Value=5
Key=[f], Value=3
Key=[c], Value=3
Key=[a], Value=3
Key=[b], Value=3
Key=[e], Value=1
```

Comment: please check... iam expecting result to be like this... Array ( [d] => 5 [a] => 3 [b] => 3 [c] => 3 [f] => 3 [e] => 1)

Comment: remove the code//echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
    //echo "<br>";and change it to like below, 
    echo $x."=>".$x_value;

Comment: check array keys..its  `d,a,b,c,f,e`  not  `d,f,c,a,b,e`

Answer (score 0):

You can use uasort for this.

```
$array = array('d' => 5, 'e' => 1, 'a' => 3, 'b' => 3, 'c' => 3, 'f' => 3);
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

I tested the code and surely it will work for you.